# Questions on tuples and user input in F#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to play around with f# to get down the basics but stuck. If you have general tips it would be greatly appreciated.

```
#light
open System
[<EntryPoint>]
let main (args : string[]) = 
match args with
    | [| firstName; lastName; city |] ->
        printfn "Hi there %s %s from %s" firstName lastName city
        0
    | _ -> failwith "Usage: HiThere.exe firstName lastName City";;
```

I get this error,

```
val main : args:string [] -> int
```

I was watching a tutorial on f# and trying to learn this function but I don't understand why I can't do it without these errors.

Comment: do you want to know why or how to fix it, please ask the question you actually want an answer to.

Comment: Which tutorial? It would help us to understand your future questions.

Comment: <code>let sumOfSquaresI nums =
    let mutable acc = 0
    for x in nums do 
        acc <- acc + sqr x
    acc</code>

this is the original problem I had from this [video](https://youtu.be/HQ887aOZITY?t=14m51s), I don't exactly understand how this works without recursion.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very minor typo in `args.[0], args.[1]. args.[2]`. You have a `.` rather than a `,` between the second and third element - it should be `args.[0], args.[1], args.[2]`.

The compiler is still able to parse it, but it interprets your code as:

```
args.[0], (args.[1].args.[2])
```

This is syntactically a two-element tuple and you are assigning it to a three-element tuple, so you get the error about tuples first. It would fail later because `args` is not a member of `args.[1]`, but that's a separate message (that the compiler ignores because it reports the one it finds earlier).

As a side-note, you could also use pattern matching on arrays and write:

```
let main (args : string[]) = 
    match args with
    | [| firstName; lastName; city |] ->
        printfn "Hi there %s %s from %s" firstName lastName city
        0
    | _ -> failwith "Usage: HiThere.exe firstName lastName City"
```

Comment: thank you! Still having trouble getting it to run though.

Comment: You probably also need to mark the `main` function with the `[<EntryPoint>]` attribute..

Comment: Yea, I have that in my main code but it wasn't showing up when I wrote it on SO.